# FFMpeg libavcodec hwaccel workings

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, vaapi, cuvid

Can anyone  explain how hwaccel decode, filter and encode  work in FFMpeg libavcodec ? 
What is the big picture ? 
What are the major functions and structures ?
Is there any difference  in how VAAPI and CUDA GPUs are handled ?
Any example code for decode, filter and encode for both VAAPI and CUDA will be great.

Comment: Check the codebase - see https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c, https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/vaapi_encode.c and https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/vaapi_transcode.c

Comment: Thanks, that is good for starting out.  However both liavcodec and ffmpeg uses different and (probably more complex) calls than  that.   For example ffmpeg does not use av_hwframe_transfer_data and av_image_copy_to_buffer for transcoding, scaling and saving an RTSP stream into a file. WIll be good to have some pointers for that level of details. Please feel free   point  in the right direction or add the content here if you can .